# Generar grupo en grafico C#

Tags: c#, .net, charts

estoy creando una grafica y los datos los consumo desde una Base de datos, solo que a la hora de crear el grafico en la linea vertical se general el nombre a que hace referencia esa serie, sin embargo necesito que la linea vertical a parezca al final del conjunto de barras, pongo imagen para que sea más entendible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede notar la linea vertical atraviesa por el centro de la serie, y necesito que la linea este hasta el final de la serie pongo imagen de ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien sabrá que linea de código tengo que implementar para que aparezca así ??

Comment: Disculpa, pero no acabo de entender lo que dices

Comment: La linea vertical (AxisX) atraviesa la serie, se tienen 4 columnas de grafico y la linea vertical atraviesa cada 2 columnas, y necesito que la linea se muestre como en la segunda imagen, hasta el final de cada 4 columnas. Me explique?? Muchas gracias

Comment: No, todavía no te entiendo, pero bueno deberías dar detalles como cual es el componente que usas para graficar, en que lo haces reportviewer o en control chart que viene con vs, habla un poco mas

Comment: Disculpa, pero lo que describes no es lo que veo en las imágenes que subiste

Comment: Lo siento, estoy utilizando un chart en C#, ya resolví mi problema, dejo la respuesta a bajo.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el código necesario, por si a alguien mas le sirve.
Mi solucion fue

```html
            //Para que las linea Verticales no se vean
            var gd = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Grid();
            gd.LineWidth = 0;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid = gd;
            //Para que las lineas verticales queden a final de cada serie
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.IntervalOffsetType = (DateTimeIntervalType)9;
```

Al final el grafico quedo así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]